# Jetty inject Spring beans into login module

Tags: spring, jetty

I have a Jetty server running with a realms.properties like this:

```
MyRealm {
    com.example.MyLoginModule required
    debug="false";
};
```

Then I have `MyLoginModule` which extends Jetty's `AbstractLoginModule`. The Jetty server creates its own Spring application context.

How can I inject beans from Jetty's Spring application context into `MyLoginModule`?

Jetty is version 9.4.35 and Spring is 5.3.4.

Also, this is code that I came across in our system rather than that I actually wrote. I am pretty familiar with Spring but not with Jetty.

Comment: Spring needs to create and/or decorate that MyLoginModule itself, way before Jetty gets a shot at it.

Comment: There's no integration from Jetty's ObjectFactory API for the LoginModule layer/handler, that means there's no automatic decoration of that component for any dependency injection API (like CDI, Spring, Guice, etc).  It would be hard to implement as well, as that LoginModule layer occurs before the Application Context is even initialized.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt thanks for the comments. Do you know if the Jetty spring context would always be initialized before `AbstractLoginModule.getUserInfo()` is called? Then I could have the Jetty Spring context create a singleton instance of the `CredentialCache` object I need, and `getUserInfo` could then call `CredentialCache.getInstance()` to get the Spring initialized instance.